# Why do most sulphate salts have water of crystallization in them?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, salt

I mean looking at most of the sulphate salts (there are so many but just to name some Epsom salt, blue vitirol, gypsum...) they have some amount of water crystallized within them (Epsom salt is MgSO4.7H2O, CuSO4.5H2O is blue vitirol and so on) so why is it like that? Is there any reason why water is crystallized in almost all metal sulphates

It isn't (maybe) related to hydration energy... nor (maybe) related to the size of the sulphate ion.

Comment: can anyone suggest me a better tag for this question please I am very confused

Comment: It is not fully clear what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Poutnik oh I meant looking at most of sulphate salts (there are so many but just to name some epsom salt, blue vitirol, gypsum etc..) they have some amount of water crystallized within them (epsom salt is MgSO4.7H2O , CuSO4.5H2O is blue vitirol and so on) so why is that? like is there any reason why water is crystallized in almost all such sulphates ? That is what I wanted to ask. Yes definitely looking at the length of my post surely told me it wasn't enough to justify

Comment: Add it rather to the question and you may ask for the question reopening via the respectively named link. Also, you may want to think longer over written text before posting it.

Comment: @Poutnik uh okay i mean this question is still dumb and maybe i shouldnt have asked it here 
but yea i am editing it thanks

Comment: Now that you've changed the meaning of the question entirely, let's look into it. BaSO4 seems to crystallize without water; so does K2SO4. Still sure about "most"? Well, maybe the majority of ***all*** salts, not just sulphates, crystallize with water in them.

Comment: @IvanNeretin oh okay but I still think (not believe) that sulphates are the most to somehow grab water in them.....you would be right though and it just may not be sulphates (like the next best bet would be chlorides)........and yea i amn't sure so waiting for more responses :)

Comment: @IvanNeretin basically I am finding for some chemical bonding-ish solution if it even exists :')

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110728/hydrate-decomposition-equation-steps

Comment: Anion barely does anything, it's the cation that can coordinate many water molecules.

Comment: [Water of crystallization is stabilized by electrostatic attractions, consequently hydrates are common for salts that contain +2 and +3 cations as well as −2 anions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_of_crystallization) Sulfate ion has -2 charge, so it is more prone to form hydrates.

Comment: @Mithoron yes that is true....

Comment: @Nilay oh is there any reason behind for which +2 and +3 attract more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sulfates commonly do have water of hydration, but so do many other salts such as chlorides. For instance, iron chlorides used in laboratory experiments at my job are commonly bought as $\ce{FeCl2•4H2O}$ and $\ce{FeCl3•6H2O}$.

One difference between sulfates and some other salts is the oxygen in the sulfate ion can form relatively strong hydrogen bonds with the protic hydrogen in water, enabling incorporation of additional water molecules into the crystal that aren't coordinated with the metal ion. Thus for instance magnesium ion commonly coordinates with six water molecules, but the [sulfate salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_sulfate) commonly incorporates a seventh water molecules in its formula unit (Epsom salt) and can even have eleven at lower temperature.

Comment: "2-" is also important. After all, that's a great deal greater than 1-.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Curiosity strikes and turns out even our old NaCl also form hydrates: [From cold (sub-freezing) solutions, salt crystallizes with water of hydration as hydrohalite (the dihydrate NaCl·2H2O NaCl·2H2O). In 2023, it was discovered that under pressure, sodium chloride can form the hydrates NaCl·8.5H2O and NaCl·13H2O.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes true

Comment: @NilayGhosh oh thats cool

Comment: hey just a quick question don't you think flourides and nitrates would also have this phenomenon?

Comment: In the case of fluorides noncoordinated water of hydration is known in some double salts; see https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1977/DT/DT9770002212.

Comment: @OscarLanzi ohkk thanks!